# How to enable locale en_EN on centOS to get i18n gettext working

Tags: php, internationalization, gettext

I have a development version of my PHP website and when I moved it to my production server on centOS OS I discovered my locale version of en_EN is not working.

Could you please tell me what can cause that and what to do to get this working? I use setlocale and gettext to use i18n in PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend anyone using `setlocale()` and `gettext()` for **localization** in PHP (there are some serious issues that will drive any developer nuts). But anyway, there is no en_EN locale. The identifier before the underscore is the language (en = English), the identifier after the underscore is the country (EN = ???). You probably should be using en_US, en_GB, or something else.

Comment: Simple associative arrays works great. They are flexible, simple to understand, doesn't require an httpd restart to reload strings, etc. Complete it with classes to support plural inflection, date/time formatting, etc. Take a look at MediaWiki source code, and you will be enlightened.

Comment: What are the serious issues you're talking about? We've been using gettext for years with PHP without problems. There is also no need to restart apache to do that.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think en_EN is correct, Perhaps you mean en_US?